# How to eliminate envelope icon when using mailto href link?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a very simple static webpage for my personal website, but have been stuck on a [image: mysterious envelope icon] that appears when using mailto and the a href tag (shown to the left of the "@" symbol):

I have opened the webpage on multiple browsers and it shows up on all of them. Does anyone know if it is part of the drop in CSS sheet I am using, and if so how to remove it? Thanks!

Here is the whole HTML code on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RDK0hUph) and here is the mailto line:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span class="myicon fa-solid fa-at"></span></a>
```

Comment: Have you tired removing any of the class in `"myicon fa-solid fa-at`? Without a [mcve] we can't do much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The envelope icon is part of the CSS stylesheet (light.css) that you are using as seen in this screenshot:

[image: css screenshot]

The fix is very simple, we can override the style being set like so:

```css
a[href^="mailto:"]::before {
    content: '';
}
```

This will remove the envelope icon from all the links where the `href` starts with "mailto:"

Alternately, if you want to remove the mail icon from just this link,

You can set a class to the link tag, for e.g.: `my-class`, like so:

```html
<a href="mailto:me@example.com" class="my-class" ...>...</a>
```

Then in your `style` tag need to add another rule like so:

```css
...

.my-class::before {
    content: '' !important;
}
```